# google app script add custom menu functions to sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I consolidate this code so that all the functions are listed under the same heading (dropdown)? Thanks.

```
function onOpen ()
{ var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();  

  var menu = [ {name: "extract e-mail",functionName: "GetAddresses"} ];  
  sheet.addMenu ("Extract E-mail", menu);    

  var menu = [ {name: "remove self",functionName: "readRows"} ];   
  sheet.addMenu ("AOA", menu); 

  var menu = [ {name: "remove duplicates",functionName: "removeDuplicates"} ];  
  sheet.addMenu ("Duplicates", menu); 

  var menu = [ {name: "send e-mail",functionName: "sendEmails"} ];  
  sheet.addMenu ("Mail Merge", menu); 

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the menu items in as an array of objects.

```
function onOpen ()
{ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();  
  var menu = [ 
    {name: "extract e-mail",functionName: "GetAddresses"},
    {name: "remove self",functionName: "readRows"},
    {name: "remove duplicates",functionName: "removeDuplicates"},
    {name: "send e-mail",functionName: "sendEmails"} 
  ];  
  sheet.addMenu ("Mail Merge", menu); 
 }
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Thought it was simple ... I just kept getting syntax errors. Works now.